# App proxy responds with 404,not working SHOPIFY

Tags: php, proxy, shopify

Being new to Shopify family, I need to get data from an external database. Currently, calling the API through APP PROXY returns 404 status. Using various code and configurations, none of my attemps were successfull.

My APP PROXY settings ary:

**Subpath prefix**: `a`
**Subpath**: `c`
**Proxy URL**: `https://my-domain.com`

**My ajax code:**

```
jQuery(function(){ //document.ready
    jQuery.get('/a/c', function( data ) {
        alert ( "DATA: " + data );
    });
});
```

NOTE: I tried `a/c/{more}` also, but it did not work either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this happening to a single store or on all the stores ? have you tried it in multiple Shopify stores ?